# In dynamic web application project the Eclipse debugger is not hitting breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse

In dynamic web application project the debugger is not hitting on breakpoints. I am working in Eclipse. Can someone please help me.
Here star representing breakpoint but doesn't hit

```
public  String addUser(HashMap hm) {
    // function logic
    logger.debug("Inside addUSer Method");
    String systemUser = getFromHMap(hm, rb.getString("USER_SYSTEMUSER"));
    ****String userID=getNextId();;
    int systemUserInt = Integer.parseInt(systemUser.trim());
    int authMethodInt = Integer.parseInt(authMethod.trim());
    if (authMethodInt == AUTHMETHOD_UN_PWD) {
        password = getFromHMap(hm, rb.getString("USER_PASSWORD"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running application in debug mode?

For this, `right click on project > debug as > debug on server`

Then it will hit the breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the server is Running in Debugging mode. 
If so, then check whether the above mentioned method is called from somewhere.